# ZeroCopy using commandline

Tags: linux, file-copy

Does any of the standard copy mechanisms take advantage of [zero copy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/)?

Ex. cp, rsync

Answer (score 2):

Well if you read more carefully the article you've provided in [Building a file Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/#N1016A) section you will see two implementations, one which uses traditional copy semantics `(File.read() and Socket.send())` is approximately 65 percent slower than the implementation which uses `transferTo() method (and in turn the sendfile() system call)` .

Long story short, zero-copy method superior standard copy mechanisms. And as far I'm aware cp/scp/rsync still use the  traditional approach.

Comment: That was my question, what unix command line has support for this if any?